# iOS Make sure documents are open before accessing

Tags: ios, core-data, document

When opening UIDocuments from a closed state, I understand that it is it done on another thread. My question is, if I have code on my main thread that will access the document (like performing a fetch request), how is it guaranteed that the document will be open before I try to access it if the opening of the closed document is done asynchronously?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to block a thread, block your application's user from accessing the document until it is open. That's what the completion handler is for.

```
- (void)openWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionHandler
```

When the completion handler is invoked simply dismiss whatever temporary user interface you display while the document is opening. This way no threads are blocked while the document is opening, and the application remains responsive (albeit useless).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `documentState` property of `UIDocument` class. For more detail refer this document [documentState description](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocument_Class/UIDocument/UIDocument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010879-CH2-DontLinkElementID_6).

It returns following enumerators to check:

```
enum {
    UIDocumentStateNormal          = 0,
    UIDocumentStateClosed          = 1 << 0,
    UIDocumentStateInConflict      = 1 << 1,
    UIDocumentStateSavingError     = 1 << 2,
    UIDocumentStateEditingDisabled = 1 << 3   }; typedef NSInteger UIDocumentState;
```

From Description:
`UIDocumentStateNormal` is what you want, as:
*The document is open, editing is enabled, and there are no conflicts or errors associated with it.*

Comment: Yea I tried doing a loop where I wait until the document state is open but it seems to block the opening of the document all together because if I removed that while loop, the document opens normally. Another weird thing is that I can perform a fetch request with no errors even before the document is opened from a closes state